# Is it possible to find columns using multiple values in Doctrine and Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

image I have the following database structure

```
class voters
{
    protected $voterid;
    protected $imageid;
    protected $action;
}

// $voterid = is the current voter
// $imageid = is the id of the voted image
// $action = is upvote/downvote,delete
```

what happens if I want to look for several items at once, to check if a column exists, 
something like

```
$dummy = findOneBy('voterid'=>1,'imageid'=>2,action=>"upvote");

if($dummy)
{
   //column exists!
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

See [Databases and Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html)

If you want to retrieve a product, regarding some properties, you just have to use the method `findOneBy` with as parameters an array :

```
$product = $repository->findOneBy(array('name' => 'foo', 'price' => 19.99));
```

Comment: Keep in mind that findOneBy throws an exception (IIRC) if there's no record found.

Comment: @Maerlyn In latest Doctrine (2.5), findOneBy() returns null if no record found - http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityRepository.html#183-196

Answer (score 5):

You must pass all values as array like this:

```
$dummy = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AcmeDemoBundle:User")->findOneBy(array(
    'voterid'=>1,
    'imageid'=>2,
    'action'=>'upvote',
));

if($dummy)
{
   //column exists!
}
```

Where key of array is a column name, value is a value in this column.

NOTE: `AcmeDemoBundle:User` - is your entity

Comment: Does this behave like an OR or like an AND?